# Turn cron job commands into executable script that can run manually

Tags: scripts, backup, rsync

I was running my crontab that backups some folders, but since then, I have started the practice of shutting down my computer at night, so I find that they do not run...go figure right? :-)

So my plan B is to create an icon that is placed on my desktop that executes an executable script file. Maybe something like backup.sh etc. So I can run the commands manually BEFORE I shut down the computer.

What is the best practice way to do this? Here is the crontab commands:

```
44 4 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /var/www/html /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/
33 3 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /home/stan/documents /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/
02 2 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /var/backups /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/
44 1 * * * mysqldump -u root -ppassword --all-databases | gzip > /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/mysql/mysqlbak-$(date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S").sql.gz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create some scripts

- `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/rsync_html`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /var/www/html /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/
  ```
- `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/rsync_documents`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /home/stan/documents /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/
  ```
- `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/rsync_backups`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /var/backups /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/
  ```
- `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/backup_mysql`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  mysqldump -u root -ppassword --all-databases | gzip > /media/stan/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/backups/mysql/mysqlbak-$(date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S").sql.gz
  ```

---

### Make the scripts executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rsync_html
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rsync_documents
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rsync_backups
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/backup_mysql
```

---

### Change your crontab

```
44 4 * * * /usr/local/bin/rsync_html
33 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/rsync_documents
02 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/rsync_backups
44 1 * * * /usr/local/bin/backup_mysql
```

---

### Create some desktop files

- `nano ~/.local/share/applications/scrip1.desktop`

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=rsync html
  Exec=/usr/local/bin/rsync_html
  Icon=
  Categories=
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=true
  ```
- `nano ~/.local/share/applications/scrip2.desktop`

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=rsync documents
  Exec=/usr/local/bin/rsync_documents
  Icon=
  Categories=
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=true
  ```
- `nano ~/.local/share/applications/scrip3.desktop`

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=rsync backup
  Exec=/usr/local/bin/rsync_backups
  Icon=
  Categories=
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=true
  ```
- `nano ~/.local/share/applications/scrip4.desktop`

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=backup mysql
  Exec=/usr/local/bin/backup_mysql
  Icon=
  Categories=
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=true
  ```

Comment: Looks awesome. It is not clear how I am to get the icons on the desktop. I still see none after following all this.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. It creates an application that I can access via application browser and I can run from there OR right click and save to desktop. Brilliant! It worked like a charm. Thanks @A.B! You are doing Gods work :-)